# How to copy a file from one branch to another branch using functionality on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Usually, I would just copy the whole content of that file in the current branch and switch to another branch on Eclipse and paste it in the new branch but I am just asking if there is a way I could do this when checking out from Eclipse?

So, I have a branch called `Mock` branch and it has a file called `a.java` and I have modified the file. Now, I switch to another branch that also has `a.java` but different from that of the `Mock` branch because I have made changes to the `a.java` in the `Mock` branch.

Now, how do I push commit on the other branch showing the differences between the `a.java` in it and that of the `Mock` branch and applying the changes in `Mock` branch to the branch I am currently on?
Is this possible in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the full content of that file, try and right click on it, [and select](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Replace_with_File_in_Git_Index):

```
Replace with -> Commit...
```

Then chose the commit from the other branch.
If you want to replace it with the latest revision from another branch, you can chose

```
Replace with -> Branch, Tag or Reference
```

[image: replace branch]

(Here I select `master` because my current branch is not `master`, and I want to replace the content of the file with the content of the same file from `master`.)

Answer (score 2):

First of all we will consider that you have pushed the changes of the other branch (so they are HEAD) and you have switched to Mock branch (of course, Im not considering merge between branches because you didn't talk about it ). Starting from this point, let me describe two possible options:

- You can do a cherry pick. Cherry pick is  a process in which you take a commit from another branch (or even the same) and apply it in your checked out one. As example, if you modify the file of branch A and commit it, you can switch to branch B  and do cherry-picking applying this commit from A to B.Of course, keep in mind that cherry pick applies ALL changes added in a commit so if  you modify a.java and b.java, both modified files will be applied as a result of the cherry pick. You can get examples from here : https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Cherry_Picking
- My favorite and most simple. Do right click in a.java and select **Compare with / Branch, tag or reference** to get a view that compares the other branch's a.java version with your current Mock branch and use Eclipse editor to apply changes (You can also use **Compare with / Commit** in case the change you want to apply wasn't at the other branch's HEAD). You can use the arrows to pass changes from right (remote branch) to left (current branch) or even do manually copy- paste

[image][image]